# S3 Upload ERROR: Header Not Signed (<HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-security-token</HeadersNotSigned>)

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In my angular project i use a presigned url generated from a aws lambda function to upload pdf document onto the s3 bucket. Now using POSTMAN the upload takes place without any error but in the angular application with http PUT request will give a 403 Forbidden Error.

**Error**

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>There were headers present in the request which were not signed</Message><HeadersNotSigned>x-amz-security-token</HeadersNotSigned><RequestId>7A2E66135748DFF3</RequestId><HostId>BT9uCZUdjI1HqycVR2QdzjyzkhKXOrVEJE5xVToeVbQup=</HostId></Error>"
```

Here is my code and Setups:

**Lambda Function**

```
 async function getSignedUrlForResume(fileName){
        const urlExpiryDuration = 5; //minutes
        console.log("inside get signed Url");
        const key = "Resume/"+fileName;
        var response = "";
        const s3Params ={ 
          Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
          Key: key,
          Expires: urlExpiryDuration*60,
          ACL: 'public-read',
          ContentType: "application/pdf"
        };
        const s3 = new AWS.S3();
        try {
          const signedUrl =  await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);
          response = {signedUrl: signedUrl};
          return response;
        } catch (error) {
          response = error;
          return response;
        }
    }
```

**Component.ts File:**

```
  async addResume(){
        let signedUrl : string =  null;

    let fileName: string = this.candidateService.candidateRecords['records'][this.candidateService.indexOfCandidate]['candidate_id']
    +"_"+
    this.candidateService.candidateRecords['records'][this.candidateService.indexOfCandidate]['first_name']
    +"_"+
    this.candidateService.candidateRecords['records'][this.candidateService.indexOfCandidate]['last_name'];
    console.log("File Name: " +fileName);

    this.file = event[0];

    await this.candidateService.getSignedUrl(fileName).then(
      (response: []) => {
        signedUrl = response['signedUrl'];
      }
    );
    console.log(signedUrl);
    console.log(this.file)
    await this.candidateService.uploadResume(signedUrl, this.file).then
    (data => {
      console.log("Upload Response:" +data);
    }).catch((err: Error) => {
      console.log('Error: '+ err);
    });
  }
```

**Component Service**

```
getSignedUrl(fileName: string){
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    queryParams = queryParams.set('fileName', fileName).set('funcName', 'getSignedUrlForResume');
    return this.http.get(AppConstants._API_END_URL, {params: queryParams})
      .pipe(
        retryAfterDelay(this.delayDuration),
        catchError((errorResponse:Error) => {
          return throwError(errorResponse.message);
        }
      )
    ).toPromise();
  }

  uploadResume(signedUrl: string, file: File){
    // Delay not added for upload to s3. since no RDS is used
    return this.http.put(signedUrl, file, {headers: {'Content-Type': file.type}}).toPromise();
  }
}
```

**HTML part:**

```
<input hidden type="file" #fileInput (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)" 
accept="application/pdf">
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there may be more, but the below needs to be updated:

```
const signedUrl =  await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);
```

to

```
const signedUrl =  await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params).promise();
```